# Creating constraints with two uiviews using snapkit

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

i'm tying to crate one UIView at the bottom with static height 60 and then a top one filling the rest. however this code seem to just make the top one fill the whole screen.

```
    //bottomWrapperView
    let bottomWrapperView = UIView()
    bottomWrapperView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.addSubview(bottomWrapperView)

    //TopWrapperView
    let topWrapperView = UIView()
    topWrapperView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    self.addSubview(topWrapperView)


    //BottomWrapperView Constraints
    bottomWrapperView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.height.equalTo(60)
        make.left.equalTo(self).offset(0)
        make.bottom.equalTo(self).offset(0)
        make.right.equalTo(self).offset(0)
        make.top.equalTo(topWrapperView)
    }



     //TopWrapperView Constraints
    topWrapperView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in

        make.left.equalTo(self).offset(0)
        make.top.equalTo(self).offset(0)
        make.bottom.equalTo(bottomWrapperView)
        make.right.equalTo(self).offset(0)
    }
```

Comment: remove "make.top.equalTo(topWrapperView)" and change "make.bottom.equalTo(bottomWrapperView)" to "make.bottom.equalTo(bottomWrapperView.snp.top)"

Comment: I wrote it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you need to make bottom constraint for `topWrapperView` equal to the top of `bottomWrapperView`

```
//BottomWrapperView Constraints
bottomWrapperView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.height.equalTo(60)
    make.left.equalTo(self).offset(0)
    make.bottom.equalTo(self).offset(0)
    make.right.equalTo(self).offset(0)
}

//TopWrapperView Constraints
topWrapperView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.left.equalTo(self).offset(0)
    make.top.equalTo(self).offset(0)
    make.bottom.equalTo(bottomWrapperView.snp.top)
    make.right.equalTo(self).offset(0)
}
```